# Server Not Started Yet (Kibana 8.1.2)

Tags: kibana

I am new to learning LogStash. So I am starting Kibana first. Then LogStash. Then a SpringBoot application that I wrote.

So in the kibana.yaml file, I only have two entries:

```
server.port: 5601
elasticsearch.hosts: ["http://my_local_hostname:9200"]
```

When I run `kibana.bat`, I see these entries in the console:

```
C:\kibana-8.1.2\bin>kibana.bat
[2022-04-18T18:06:38.673+05:30][INFO ][plugins-service] Plugin "metricsEntities" is disabled.
[2022-04-18T18:06:38.742+05:30][INFO ][http.server.Preboot] http server running at http://localhost:5601
[2022-04-18T18:06:38.775+05:30][INFO ][plugins-system.preboot] Setting up [1] plugins: [interactiveSetup]
[2022-04-18T18:06:38.806+05:30][WARN ][config.deprecation] The default mechanism for Reporting privileges will work differently in future versions, which will affect the behavior of this cluster. Set "xpack.reporting.roles.enabled" to "false" to adopt the future behavior before upgrading.
[2022-04-18T18:06:38.950+05:30][INFO ][plugins-system.standard] Setting up [112] plugins: [translations,licensing,globalSearch,globalSearchProviders,features,mapsEms,licenseApiGuard,usageCollection,taskManager,telemetryCollectionManager,telemetryCollectionXpack,kibanaUsageCollection,sharedUX,share,embeddable,uiActionsEnhanced,screenshotMode,screenshotting,banners,telemetry,newsfeed,fieldFormats,expressions,dataViews,charts,esUiShared,bfetch,data,savedObjects,presentationUtil,expressionShape,expressionRevealImage,expressionRepeatImage,expressionMetric,expressionImage,customIntegrations,home,searchprofiler,painlessLab,grokdebugger,management,watcher,licenseManagement,advancedSettings,spaces,security,savedObjectsTagging,reporting,lists,fileUpload,ingestPipelines,encryptedSavedObjects,dataEnhanced,cloud,snapshotRestore,eventLog,actions,alerting,triggersActionsUi,transform,stackAlerts,ruleRegistry,savedObjectsManagement,console,controls,graph,fleet,indexManagement,remoteClusters,crossClusterReplication,indexLifecycleManagement,visualizations,canvas,visTypeXy,visTypeVislib,visTypeVega,visTypeTimeseries,rollup,visTypeTimelion,visTypeTagcloud,visTypeTable,visTypeMetric,visTypeHeatmap,visTypeMarkdown,dashboard,maps,dashboardEnhanced,expressionTagcloud,expressionPie,visTypePie,expressionMetricVis,expressionHeatmap,expressionGauge,dataViewFieldEditor,lens,cases,timelines,discover,osquery,observability,discoverEnhanced,dataVisualizer,ml,uptime,securitySolution,infra,upgradeAssistant,monitoring,logstash,enterpriseSearch,apm,dataViewManagement]
[2022-04-18T18:06:38.967+05:30][INFO ][plugins.taskManager] TaskManager is identified by the Kibana UUID: e299f8d2-8da2-4387-8572-2485272aab82
[2022-04-18T18:06:39.094+05:30][WARN ][plugins.security.config] Generating a random key for xpack.security.encryptionKey. To prevent sessions from being invalidated on restart, please set xpack.security.encryptionKey in the kibana.yml or use the bin/kibana-encryption-keys command.
[2022-04-18T18:06:39.095+05:30][WARN ][plugins.security.config] Session cookies will be transmitted over insecure connections. This is not recommended.
[2022-04-18T18:06:39.111+05:30][WARN ][plugins.security.config] Generating a random key for xpack.security.encryptionKey. To prevent sessions from being invalidated on restart, please set xpack.security.encryptionKey in the kibana.yml or use the bin/kibana-encryption-keys command.
[2022-04-18T18:06:39.112+05:30][WARN ][plugins.security.config] Session cookies will be transmitted over insecure connections. This is not recommended.
[2022-04-18T18:06:39.125+05:30][WARN ][plugins.reporting.config] Generating a random key for xpack.reporting.encryptionKey. To prevent sessions from being invalidated on restart, please set xpack.reporting.encryptionKey in the kibana.yml or use the bin/kibana-encryption-keys command.
[2022-04-18T18:06:39.136+05:30][WARN ][plugins.encryptedSavedObjects] Saved objects encryption key is not set. This will severely limit Kibana functionality. Please set xpack.encryptedSavedObjects.encryptionKey in the kibana.yml or use the bin/kibana-encryption-keys command.
[2022-04-18T18:06:39.149+05:30][WARN ][plugins.actions] APIs are disabled because the Encrypted Saved Objects plugin is missing encryption key. Please set xpack.encryptedSavedObjects.encryptionKey in the kibana.yml or use the bin/kibana-encryption-keys command.
[2022-04-18T18:06:39.161+05:30][WARN ][plugins.alerting] APIs are disabled because the Encrypted Saved Objects plugin is missing encryption key. Please set xpack.encryptedSavedObjects.encryptionKey in the kibana.yml or use the bin/kibana-encryption-keys command.
[2022-04-18T18:06:39.177+05:30][INFO ][plugins.ruleRegistry] Installing common resources shared between all indices
[2022-04-18T18:06:39.791+05:30][INFO ][plugins.screenshotting.config] Chromium sandbox provides an additional layer of protection, and is supported for Win32 OS. Automatically enabling Chromium sandbox.
[2022-04-18T18:06:41.151+05:30][ERROR][elasticsearch-service] Unable to retrieve version information from Elasticsearch nodes. connect EACCES 192.168.1.19:9200
[2022-04-18T18:06:41.329+05:30][INFO ][plugins.screenshotting.chromium] Browser executable: C:\kibana-8.1.2\x-pack\plugins\screenshotting\chromium\chrome-win\chrome.exe
```

The console entries do look fine. Although I dont understand a lot of entries yet.

But when I enter `http://localhost:5601/` on the browser, I get the webpage:

> Kibana server is not ready yet.

But after a while I do see this pop up in the console:

```
[2022-04-18T18:26:39.188+05:30][ERROR][plugins.ruleRegistry] Error: Timeout: it took more than 1200000ms
    at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\kibana-8.1.2\x-pack\plugins\rule_registry\server\rule_data_plugin_service\resource_installer.js:54:20)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:559:17)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7)
[2022-04-18T18:26:39.195+05:30][ERROR][plugins.ruleRegistry] Error: Failure installing common resources shared between all indices. Timeout: it took more than 1200000ms
    at ResourceInstaller.installWithTimeout (C:\kibana-8.1.2\x-pack\plugins\rule_registry\server\rule_data_plugin_service\resource_installer.js:63:13)
    at ResourceInstaller.installCommonResources (C:\kibana-8.1.2\x-pack\plugins\rule_registry\server\rule_data_plugin_service\resource_installer.js:77:5)
```

Can you please tell me what am is going wrong here. I see that it's a common problem. But I tried a lot of the solutions provided on SO, but nothing worked yet.

Answer (score 0):

You've got an error:

```
[2022-04-18T18:06:41.151+05:30][ERROR][elasticsearch-service] Unable to retrieve version information from Elasticsearch nodes. connect EACCES 192.168.1.19:9200
```

Did you upgrade all of software? Elastic, Kibana, Logstash (+Filebeat if needed).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).